# Configure: error: Cannot locate a valid Visual Studio installation when build jdk

Tags: build, java-17

I'm trying to build openjdk-17 on Windows 11 (Home Version).

```bash
bash configure --with-boot-jdk='/mnt/c/program files/java/jdk-16' --with-toolchain-version=2019 --enable-debug
```

Here is a error when I run it :

> Configure: error: Cannot locate a valid Visual Studio installation

I have set short name for `C:\Program Files (x86)` and installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 update 16.11.27

Why it happened?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `--with-tools-dir`?

Comment: @JornVernee Thanks a lot, I solved this problem by your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem, Thanks to [Jorn Vernee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3699139/jorn-vernee).

My problem is missing `--with-tools-dir`, it should be

```
[Visual studio install dir]\VC\Auxiliary\Build
```

> Replace the [Visual studio install dir] with real install directory.

---

But there still a issue when using Chinese Windows version, `cl.exe` will localization itself's output message. This make the `generated-configure.sh` report a `Target CPU mismatch.` error when double-check target cpu type.

[Here](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/6115) is a issue about `cl.exe` 's localization.

My solution is delete the double-check code in `generated-configure.sh` because  I'm sure the cpu type is match. Please let me know if somebody know's there is a better solution.